# Get windows system folders (user home directory, "My documents", etc) path in R

Tags: r

I would like to get the full path of user's home folder (usually something like C:\Users\%USERNAME%) or "My documents" folder and can't find the way to do this from R script. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: what do you mean by home folder? Do you mean `getwd()`?

Comment: no, `getwd()` gives only the active directory of current R instance while I need the directory of current Windows user profile.

Comment: The __user's home__ directory on Linux/Mac is on Windows the __user's profile__ directory. There is predefined a [Windows Environment Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for this directory which is `USERPROFILE`. So `"%USERPROFILE%"` should be used on Windows command line to access the user's home/profile directory because of this directory can be on any drive in any directory and not only in __default__ directory `C:\Users` as on __default__ installation of Windows Vista and later Windows versions. Note: The word __default__ does not mean __always__.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you want:

```
path.expand('~')
```

Comment: This gives me the path "C:/Users/user_x/Documents". What if I want the path  "C:/Users/user_x".

Comment: `dirname(path.expand('~'))` should work if if you don't want to use another package

Comment: @LisaB. `'~'` will expand to whatever `HOME` is set to (See `?EnvVar` for details). On windows you could use `Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")`, and likewise, on windows  I personally set the `HOME` variable to `USERPROFILE` automatically in every R session by appending `--no-save --no-restore  HOME=%USERPROFILE%` to the end of the `Target` in the properties of my shortcut (Icon) for R.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But if I assume that not all Windows users did this and I want it to work for every Windows user?

Comment: `Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")` will work for all windows users

Answer (score 2):

With the package `fs`, you can also get the home directory:

`library(fs)`

`path_home()`

Comment: Cool package. I didn't know Hadley had done a file system package. Love that it's cross platform, but wouldn't normally use a package for something so simple.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: As I said above the usual path.expand() did not work for me, this one does. I know I should spend more time on setting my `HOME` variable. But this fs package seems to be smart enough, so I don't need to do it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To get C:/Users/%USERNAME% without any extra package (or, with "base") you can use

```
Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")
```

The `path.expand('~')` suggested above gave me the equivalent of  C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Documents

obs: that worked for me in Win 10 and Win11 and with R3.4 and 4.1