# How to use Windows special directories in R

Tags: r

If I do `list.files('~')` on Linux I get the contents of my home directory.

If I do `list.files('%userprofiles%')` from Windows, I get an empty character as the return.

How can I use the special directories in this manner on Windows?

This isn't the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620582/get-windows-system-folders-user-home-directory-my-documents-etc-path-in-r) because using `~` in Windows gets me `%userprofile%/documents` which I don't want.  As a plan B I can use that and use string manipulation to take out "/documents" but that seems pretty hacky.

Comment: chekc out `list.files(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"))`

Comment: @rawr I think you mean '~/..` and surprisingly enough, yes that does work

Comment: @nongkrong make it an answer and I think you win.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor feel free to add it if you want

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yes that would have made more sense :}

Comment: I posted @nongkrong's comment as an answer.  If there's another way that will work for all special directories then I'll accept that answer, preferably one that uses the '%' symbol to look more like how one would access the directories in explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @nongkrong's comments...

`Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")` will return the correct directory.  Using `Sys.getenv()` will work for other special directories too.  Fortunately it is possible to mix "\\", which `Sys.getenv()` returns, with "/" which are more convenient to use for full paths.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would consider this "hacky", but you can try something like:

```
list.files(dirname(path.expand("~")))
```

Comment: I like this better than my plan B of `gsub`ing out the documents directory but I like @nongkrong's solution in the comments better because it actually answers the question for all special directory names